# MySQL - JDBC - SELECT and DELETE at the same time

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So my client program runs this code to get the rows data and delete it after. The thing is between the SELECT and DELETE there is a 60-130 millisecond delay and in that time another client could have grabbed the same row. Is there any way I can SELECT and DELETE at the same time to stop this conflict from happening?

```
String filterQuery = "SELECT token_id FROM table WHERE expires <= ? LIMIT 1;";

PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(filterQuery);
preparedStmt.setLong(1, System.currentTimeMillis());
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
ResultSet result = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
String token_id = null;
while (result.next()) {
    System.out.println(result.getString(1));
    token_id = result.getString(1);
}

filterQuery = "DELETE FROM table WHERE token_id = ?;";
preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(filterQuery);
preparedStmt.setString(1, token_id);
preparedStmt.execute();
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime+" milliseconds");
```

Comment: @isaace That is not a proper solution with databases.

Comment: You will need to disable auto commit use a proper transaction isolation level, and maybe use a `select .. for update` or something similar to explicitly lock the record (not sure about the specifics for MySQL)`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the response I will be sure to give it a go as soon as i get back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your SELECT to block subsequent reads on that row until you delete it then, as Mark indicates in his comment, you'll need to

- enable transactions (`setAutoCommit(false)`)
- set transaction isolation to SERIALIZABLE, and
- use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`

This sample code works for me:

```java
conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT token_id FROM tokens ORDER BY token_id LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE");
rs.next();
int token_id = rs.getInt("token_id");
System.out.printf("Got %d.%n", token_id);
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM tokens WHERE token_id=?");
ps.setInt(1, token_id);
ps.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
```

Comment: Alright thanks a lot I will try that as soon as I'm back and let you know how it works out. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Thanks so much really appreciate the help! The solution works exactly how i wanted it to :)

Answer (score 0):

Editing the whole answer since I misunderstood the question XD

Take a look at mySQL REPEATABLE READ, your SQ code will look similar to this

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT token_id FROM table WHERE expires <= 'Example';
DELETE FROM table WHERE token_id = 'ExampleID!';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I need the data of the row (token_id) before it's deleted

Comment: Oh, sorry mate, I misunderstood the problem, i'll edit my answer :D

Comment: It's probably considered better form to use the JDBC API for controlling the transaction, e.g., `Connection#setTransactionIsolation`, `Connection#setAutoCommit`, `Connection#commit` rather than using native SQL commands, e.g., `SET ...`, `START TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT`