# Read from database and delete from database through spring batch

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have to read data from Relational database and delete all the data which is present in the table through spring batch.

Is there any way to do so?

I have tried reading through jdbscursorItemReader and update delete query in ItemWriter Also, by Itemprocessor but failed to do it.

Being new makes it difficult for me to perform it to its accuracy.
As I'm not getting any error in both cases but data is not getting deleted.

Comment: `but failed to do it.`: How did it fail? Can you share your attempt and show the stack trace of the error you get? I'm not sure you can delete the data you are reading in one go (I never tried that). You can try a [SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749963/mysql-jdbc-select-and-delete-at-the-same-time) but not all databases support it. Is using two steps for this an option for you? ie a step to determine/mark records for deletion and a second (tasklet) step to delete those records.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud Ben Hassine,    I m using reader to read from the db in which I'm writing a select query. And failing as in my application is running just fine but not able to delete anything from database.

Comment: Please share your code and your queries to be able to help you in an efficient manner. And again, if this does not work, is using two steps an option for you?